# Redirect copy of stdout and stderr to one file, copy of just stderr to another file from within bash script

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection

Note that I have reviewed both stackoverflow questions below, but my question is different:

- [redirect COPY of stdout to log file from within bash script itself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3173131/160984)
- [redirect stdout and stderr to one file, copy of just stderr to another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32532728/160984)

In attempting to do this, I have the following test.sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm stdout_and_stderr.log
rm stderr.log

exec 2> >(tee -ia stderr.log >> stdout_and_stderr.log) 1> >(tee -ia stdout_and_stderr.log)

echo "stdout"
echo "stderr" >&2
```

The only problem is that stderr is not displayed to terminal:

```
$ ./test.sh > /dev/null
$ ./test.sh 2> /dev/null
$ stdout
```

My version of bash:

```
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
```

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that works:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm stdout_and_stderr.log
rm stderr.log

exec 2> >(tee -ia stdout_and_stderr.log >&2)
exec 2> >(tee -ia stderr.log >&2)
exec 1> >(tee -ia stdout_and_stderr.log)

echo "stdout"
echo "stderr" >&2
```

It can also be done in one line:

```
exec 1> >(tee -ia stdout_and_stderr.log) 2> >(tee -ia stdout_and_stderr.log >&2) 2> >(tee -ia stderr.log >&2)
```